# how does classError work in mclust package?

Tags: r, classification

```
true <- c(1,1,1,2,3,3)
pred <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)

library(mclust)

classError(true, pred)
```

The outputs are misclassified 4 and error rate 0.16667.

I don't know how it gives 0.16667 error rate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of [`mclust::classError`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mclust/versions/6.0.1/topics/classError) explains that

> If more than one mapping between predicted classification and the known truth corresponds to the minimum number of classification errors, only one possible set of misclassified observations is returned.

The minimum error mapping between `pred` and `true` is 1 ⇔ 1, 2 ⇔ 3 (and the true 2 is misclassified).

```r
true <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3)
pred <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)

mclust::classError(true, pred)
#> $misclassified
#> [1] 4
#> 
#> $errorRate
#> [1] 0.1666667
```

Specify the possible labels explicitly to get the expected result of 2 errors out 6 data points.

```r
pred2 <- factor(pred, levels = 1:3)
true2 <- factor(true, levels = 1:3)

mclust::classError(true2, pred2)
#> $misclassified
#> [1] 5 6
#> 
#> $errorRate
#> [1] 0.3333333
```